# how close was kabuto to achieving the power of sage of six paths?

Tags: naruto

In the anime after kabuto received his sage mode  He claimed he was the closest thing to sage of six path. but how close was he in reality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no measured way of saying this, but considering how poorly his control over sage chakra was, because of how much his appearance changed, I guess he was just being arrogant. He wasn't even truly capable of absorbing natural energy, since he implanted himself with cells from Jūgo to absorb natural energy constantly. He also wasn't aware, at that time, of how strong Naruto had become and what his power consisted of, so in summary, he was not the closest thing to the Sage of Six Paths nor he was close to anything like it.

Comment: ahh okay, yes that makes sence

Answer (score 0):

He is nowhere close to the power of sage of six paths. The power of sage of six paths is not a power that you can achieve easily, especially through Kabuto way to implant Orochimaru cells to his body. If you have Rinnegan, then we can say you already achieve the power of sage of six paths.